# scrollTo doesn't work in modal component but scrollIntoView does

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal sort of menu component that has a scroll. Today I've got some trouble with scrolling.

I wanna make some function that will scroll this component to the top. And I find the answer with scrollIntoView. But this does not perfectly work because it's scrolling only at the top of the visible part.

Unfortunately, I have padding and without that, my modal doesn't look actually good.

I thought `scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0})` would help me but it's not working.

**There is some code that I use now:**

```
// state  that open & hide modal window
const [modalStatus, setModalStatus] = useState(false);

const myRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current?.scrollIntoView({block: 'start'});
    
    // Doesn't work
    // myRef.current?.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0});
}, [modalStatus]);

return(
    <div className={modalStatus ? "modal" : "modal__disabled"}>
        <div ref={myRef} className="modal__content">
            Many content with scroll
        </div>
    </div>
);
```